# How to diable a option in select_tag and make a option as default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a select_tag and making one option value as default and i want to make some option as disabled based on a condition

```
<% disabled_option = ["options for disabled"]%> 
<%= select_tag "product_dropdown", options_for_select(ProductType.get_all_products, @type), {:disabled => disabled_options} %>
```

the above code is throwing an error **wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)** 
even I have used

```
<%= select_tag "product_dropdown", options_for_select(ProductType.get_all_products, @type, {:disabled => disabled_options}) %>
```

This is also not working how can i do that

Comment: If i keep outside the options as you specified the select_tag itself is disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the syntax for `options_for_select`

```
 options_for_select(["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"], disabled: ["value1", "value4"])
```

And you are passing three `arguments`

```
options_for_select(ProductType.get_all_products, @type, {:disabled => disabled_options})
```

So it should be like below, where `ProductType.get_all_products` should be an `array`

**EDIT**

```
options_for_select(ProductType.get_all_products, selected: @type, disabled: disabled_options)
```

Comment: type is value which is a default option value. By default the select tag should have a default value which is stored in type variable